# CKEditor disappeared

Tags: wysiwyg

Was in my Drupal 6 site editing some pages and CKEditer suddenly disappeared in the Edit screens.

I did nothing to anything else & have no idea why the CKeditor fields are no longer showing up when I edit content?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to do the following and I hope it will fix your issue

- Clear drupal cache then check CKeditor field
- If nothing changed then try to open your site on different browser
- If nothing changed then try to look if you have any javascript errors when you edit any content/node/settings; use firefox with firebug add-on
- If nothing changed then try to uninstall the module then install it again
- Also try to disable javascript optimization under performance menu

Comment: Even though it's a wordpress page, this is a good summary of how to debugging javascript issues: https://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Your_Browser_to_Diagnose_JavaScript_Errors